# Removing all duplicated lines from a file in Python/NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

My problem is with removing both duplicated lines. I have a text file:

```
192.168.1.18 --- B8:27:EB:48:C3:B6
192.168.1.12 --- 00:A0:57:2E:A6:12
192.168.1.11 --- 00:1D:A2:80:3C:CC
192.168.1.7 --- F0:9F:C2:0A:48:E7
192.168.1.6 --- 80:2A:A8:C9:85:1C
192.168.1.1 --- F0:9F:C2:05:B7:A6
192.168.1.9 --- DC:4A:3E:DF:22:06
192.168.1.8 --- 80:2A:A8:C9:8E:F6
192.168.1.1 --- F0:9F:C2:05:B7:A6

192.168.1.7 --- F0:9F:C2:0A:48:E7

192.168.1.12 --- 00:A0:57:2E:A6:12

192.168.1.11 --- 00:1D:A2:80:3C:CC

192.168.1.6 --- 80:2A:A8:C9:85:1C

192.168.1.8 --- 80:2A:A8:C9:8E:F6
```

The text file is exactly as it looks like. Please help me with that i want to remove both duplicated lines so it only stays:

```
192.168.1.18 --- B8:27:EB:48:C3:B6

192.168.1.9 --- DC:4A:3E:DF:22:06
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: As mentioned above, you can use Pandas. Numpy also has `unique` function for dropping duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another short alternative with `collections.Counter` object:

```
import collections

with open('lines.txt', 'r') as f:
    for k,c in collections.Counter(f.read().splitlines()).items():
        if c == 1:
            print(k)
```

The output:

```
192.168.1.18 --- B8:27:EB:48:C3:B6
192.168.1.9 --- DC:4A:3E:DF:22:06
```

Comment: You can just pass the file object `f` to `Counter`, rather than doing `read().splitlines()` on it first.

Comment: @Blckknght, no, that won't work because of intermediate blank lines

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thank you! Your answer is what i have been searching for :)

Comment: @A.Babik, you're welcome

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I wonder now how would i detect a changes in text file. Example: if there is a new line/s from the last time it was read. Any idea?

Comment: @A.Babik, that's another case for another question

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot of detail in the question, you've tagged `numpy`, is that a requirement or just an interest?

If you have no specific requirement, do it using the standard library:

```
d = {}
with open('/file/path', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line not in d:
            d[line] = 1
        else:
            d[line] += 1

no_dup = [line for line in d if d[line] < 2]
```

Comment: This is not numpy either...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes I realize that. I unfortunately don't have a lot of `numpy` experience. While its tagged in the post, I didn't see a specific request for a solution specific to that library. If you can do it simply with the standard library, why not?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, it's not mandatory to do it exactly on numpy. The main tags are `python`, `python3`, `...`

Comment: @shash678 In your case the answer was incorrect anyway. But in general, you shouldn't make assumptions about things like that. Ask the OP for clarification.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Fair point. As such I made an edit asking the OP for clarification but still retained my solution for now.

Comment: Thanks for your time guys :)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
Using `numpy`

First, load your file with *`np.loadtxt`*.

```
x = np.loadtxt('file.txt', dtype=str, delimiter=',') 
                              # bogus delimiter so that a 1D array is loaded
```

Next, use *`np.unique`* with `return_counts=True`, and find all unique entries that were not repeated.

```
unique, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
out = unique[counts == 1]

out
array(['192.168.1.18 --- B8:27:EB:48:C3:B6',
       '192.168.1.9 --- DC:4A:3E:DF:22:06'],
      dtype='<U34')
```

---

**Option 2**
Using `pandas`

Load your data using *`pd.read_csv`* and then call *`drop_duplicates`*.

```
df  = pd.read_csv('file.txt', delimiter=',', header=None)

df
                                     0
0   192.168.1.18 --- B8:27:EB:48:C3:B6
1   192.168.1.12 --- 00:A0:57:2E:A6:12
2   192.168.1.11 --- 00:1D:A2:80:3C:CC
3    192.168.1.7 --- F0:9F:C2:0A:48:E7
4    192.168.1.6 --- 80:2A:A8:C9:85:1C
5    192.168.1.1 --- F0:9F:C2:05:B7:A6
6    192.168.1.9 --- DC:4A:3E:DF:22:06
7    192.168.1.8 --- 80:2A:A8:C9:8E:F6
8    192.168.1.1 --- F0:9F:C2:05:B7:A6
9    192.168.1.7 --- F0:9F:C2:0A:48:E7
10  192.168.1.12 --- 00:A0:57:2E:A6:12
11  192.168.1.11 --- 00:1D:A2:80:3C:CC
12   192.168.1.6 --- 80:2A:A8:C9:85:1C
13   192.168.1.8 --- 80:2A:A8:C9:8E:F6

df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
                                    0
0  192.168.1.18 --- B8:27:EB:48:C3:B6
6   192.168.1.9 --- DC:4A:3E:DF:22:06
```

To save to your text, you can use *`pd.to_csv`*:

```
df.to_csv('file.txt', delimiter='')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @COLDSPEED made it :) Thanks for the answer again.

Comment: @A.Babik you can only accept one. I hope you made sure you accepted the one you meant to (I got a notification too, that's why I ask)

Comment: @COLDSPEED I wish i could accept both because both answers are correct. I have accepted the one with the most clean output.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I wonder now how would i detect a changes in text file. Example: if there is a new line/s from the last time it was read. Any idea?